# Call to js file not working on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm working on a project based on an online course.
I'm trying to call a js file to run and it's not working.
Here is the call at the end of index.cshtml

```
@section scripts {
    alert("before");
    <script src="~/js/product.js">
        alert("inside");
    </script>
alert("after");
}
```

I can't get the window.alert message at the beginning of product.js (see screenshot below) to show up on runtime.
Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Do you have any error in the network tab in the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: Thanks, it was a syntax error, i didnt know syntax errors are not shown on js files :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `src` attribute inside your `script` tag. If there is a `src` attribute, the code inside the `src` element will not run; instead, the js file that's linked will run.
Remove the `src` tag, which will be like this change your code to this:

```
@section scripts {
    alert("before");
    <script>
        alert("inside");
    </script>
alert("after");
}
```

Now your alert will run.

Answer (score 0):

If your `@RenderSection("scripts")` is inside a  tag, I would recommend you don't set it up that way, so that you can do the following:

```
@section scripts {
  <script type="text/javascript">alert("Before");</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=".."></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">alert("After");</script>
}
```

A script tag inside another script tag isn't going to work correctly, so I would recommend place the `@RenderSection("scripts")` at an appropriate place in the layout, but not inside a script tag, so that you can nest multiple scripts together as needed.